# How to make a boxplot image very wide in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, ipynb

I'm working with pandas and a few other visualization libraries in a Jupyter Notebook. I have a dataframe with 80 columns (variables). I want to make a very wide boxplot image so I can see each boxplot.

When I use the simple boxplot method it horizontally compresses the image so it can all be seen at once.

[image]

I would like to horizontally stretch the image so each boxplot can be seen. Ideally I would be scrolling to the side to look at all of the plots.

Edit: After using the figsize parameter I'm thinking maybe the problem is the Jupyter notebook scaling the image down. Has anyone ever experienced this with Jupyter?

This is after using figsize.
[image]

But its just too small to see.

Comment: Maybe the `figsize` parameter?

Comment: Thanks @BigBen that did help! now I just need to figure out how to stop jupyter from scaling the image down!

Comment: You could also try plt.tight_layout() - this might help ensure that the whole image is maintained without scaling down.

Comment: I realized I shouldn't have been trying to put all of the boxplot's in the same image. The scale for SalePrice of a house made NumberofBedrooms impossible to see. I ended up printing a new boxplot for each variable.